# How to rename and move a file using java code without erasing the content

Tags: java, rename, move

On renaming and moving a file using java code,the contents of the file is removed.How to rename and move a file using java code without erasing the content

Comment: If renaming and moving a file (i.e. moving a file) caused the contents of the file to be removed, it would be pretty useless, wouldn't it? Now obviously your code has a bug. Show it.

Comment: Move the content of the file to a new file with a different name

Comment: Why tag it with 'selenium'?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code, it can rename and copy the file into different folder

```
package han.code.development;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileRenameandMove
{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
       File file=new File("D:\\Haneef\\Stackoverflow\\files.txt");
       FileReader fileR=new FileReader(file);
       BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fileR);
       String str=bufferedReader.readLine();
       FileWriter fileW=new FileWriter(new File("D:\\Haneef\\Stackoverflow\\Move\\File1.txt"));
       fileW.write(str);
       fileW.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: method for newfile?

Comment: that's new File() and also it can copy the texts from the "files.txt" to "File1.txt" using BufferedReader

Comment: Hi @Jen, is that solved or do you need help on this?

Answer (score 0):

try{

```
            File afile =new File("C:\\Users\\Jen\\Downloads\\usage.csv");

            File bfile =new File("C:\\Users\\Jen\\Desktop\\BJ\\");



             inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile + "\\"+ dd.get(j).getText()+ "_March _2018.csv");

            Thread.sleep(1000);



             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];



             int length;

            //copy the file content in bytes

             while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){



                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);              

             }



             inStream.close();

            outStream.close();

        // if file copied successfully then delete the original file

        afile.delete();

        System.out.println("File moved successfully");



         }catch(IOException e){

             e.printStackTrace();

         }

    }
```